# Seg fault when trying to init an array of structs

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I am just trying to initialize an array of structs using a separate function in c but when i call the function it causes the program to crash due to seg fault.

All i want to do is initialize the value and set the pos = to k+1 using a loop of the size n a constant of 20 can anyone help, perhaps their is something which is i am completely missing thanks.

Code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #define n 20
    
    typedef struct history {
        char* value;
        int pos;
    } hist;

hist* history_struct[n];

void init_struct() {
    /* this function will create an array of structs of size 20*/
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        history_struct[k]->value = (hist*) malloc(sizeof(hist*));
        history_struct[k]->pos = k+1;
        printf("indexes = %d ", history_struct[k]->pos);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You does not have an array of structures. You declared an array of pointers to structures. This expression history_struct[k] yields a null pointer.

Comment: change that to `hist history_struct[n];` or you need to `malloc` memory for each `hist*` in `history_struct` before dereferencing them. Also, `history_struct[k]->value = (hist*) malloc(sizeof(hist*));` is odd. There's no need to cast the return value of `malloc`, and in this case you cast it to the wrong thing. `value` is a `char*`, not a `hist*`. Furthermore, `sizeof(hist*)` is going to be 4 or 8 depending on your architecture, and is a weird method from which to derive string length.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how can i fix this then i remove the pointer from line hist* history_struct[n]; but that is now causing other errors in the loop

Comment: Your malloc allocates enough memory for a pointer to a `hist`, but you want to allocate memory for a `hist` and store the pointer to that `hist`, so write `history_struct[k]->value = malloc(sizeof(hist));`.

Comment: @WernerHenze why could i not juse use malloc(sizeof(*char)) would that not be sufficient

Comment: @Jimbhoy I just saw my fault. You are not allocating memory for a `hist` but for... what exactly? Also: you are missing a `#include <stdlib.h>`. Please compile with higher warning level and you will see that your assignment to `value` is wrong. Also you have an array of pointers to `hist`, but none of them points to any memory. Change your global array from `hist*` to `hist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have declared an array of pointers to structs, simple clean up of the code will sort you out from the null pointer you seem to be having. You also use malloc in a weird way if value is just a char* then just take the `sizeof(char*)` and there is no need to cast

```
hist history_struct[n];

    void init_struct() {
        /* this function will create an array of structs of size 20*/
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            history_struct[k].value = malloc(sizeof(char*));
            history_struct[k].pos = k+1;
            printf("indexes = %d ", history_struct[k].pos);
        }
        
    }
```

so we remove the pointer then meaning we got back to the dot notation instead of "->" as we are no longer using a pointer hope this helped and sorted out your issue any further questions just ask me

Comment: this sorted my problem and i understand it now thanks a lot!